# Merge two lists with labels

Tags: python, list

I want to merge two sorted lists into a new sorted lists, but I want to include labels into the new list to see which list was the origin of each value.

So far that's my code:

```
l1 = [1, 40, 90, 104]
l2 = [5, 20, 70, 85, 230]
test = [(i, "l1") for i in l1 ] + [(i, "l2") for i in l2]
test.sort() 
print test

 [(1, 'l1'), (5, 'l2'), (20, 'l2'), (40, 'l1'), (70, 'l2'), (85, 'l2'), (90, 'l1'), (104, 'l1'), (230, 'l2')]
```

I'm using Python 2.7.6. Is there a faster way to do this? Because my lists will be very long (hundreds of thousand)

Comment: Do you know in advance that the two lists `l1` and `l2` are themselves sorted?  If so, then yes, if not, I don't think so.

Comment: does (l1 + l2).sort() gives you same time or different ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l1 = [1, 40, 90, 104]
l2 = [5, 20, 70, 85, 230]
```

you can choose your way of labelling:

```
ll1 = [(i, "l1") for i in l1]
ll2 = [(i, "l2") for i in l2]
```

or

```
import itertools
ll1i = zip(l1,itertools.repeat('l1'))
ll2i = zip(l2,itertools.repeat('l2'))
```

then either you sort it out:

```
test = sorted(ll1 + ll2)
```

or you can use `heapq.merge`:

```
import heapq
test = list(heapq.merge(ll1, ll2))
```

or use the generators with heapq:

```
ll1g = ((i, "l1") for i in l1)
ll2g = ((i, "l2") for i in l2)
test = list(heapq.merge(ll1g, ll2g))
```

N.B.: usually, using list comprehension or generators has better performance in python
than using `itertools`. The default `sort` algorithm is usually performing pretty well, 
but if the lists are already sorted, `heapq.merge` may work best.

Using [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/timeit.html) with Python3 on a 2.5GHz Core2Quad, here are the benchmarks (for 1000000 repeats of the func):

using itertools:

```
>>> timeit.Timer(lambda: heapq.merge(ll1i, ll2i)).repeat()
[0.4750211238861084, 0.4694850444793701, 0.46796107292175293]
>>> timeit.Timer(lambda: sorted(list(ll1i)+list(ll2i))).repeat()
[1.9459788799285889, 1.9470620155334473, 1.9455249309539795]
```

using lists:

```
>>> timeit.Timer(lambda: sorted(ll1+ll2)).repeat()
[2.1228671073913574, 2.125030994415283, 2.1156458854675293]
>>> timeit.Timer(lambda: list(heapq.merge(ll1,ll2)) ).repeat()
[9.534330129623413, 9.518659830093384, 9.540029048919678]
```

using generators:

```
>>> timeit.Timer(lambda: sorted(itertools.chain(ll1g, ll2g))).repeat()
[1.2377429008483887, 1.2369508743286133, 1.2312331199645996]
>>> timeit.Timer(lambda: list(heapq.merge(ll1g,ll2g)) ).repeat()
[3.9007039070129395, 3.9058940410614014, 3.9031548500061035]
```

do your own benchmarks, and choose the solution that fits best to your context!

*edited to include ending ')'

Answer (score 3):

I usually use itertools for this kind of thing

```
import itertools
l1 = [1, 40, 90, 104]
l2 = [5, 20, 70, 85, 230]

test = zip(l1,itertools.repeat('li')) + zip(l2,itertools.repeat('l2'))
```

Comment: Using itertools is cool, but I'm not sure this will actually be *faster*.

Comment: Update: Quick testing indicates that it will be, [by more than 20% in fact](http://pastebin.com/SFi9fYjP).

Comment: In my experience it's faster with very large collections, but I usually check before I decide which way to go. I did a rough test on this with sorted lists of a million long and it was quite a bit faster.

Comment: it's being a surprise to me as well, as I'm saying in my answer, I usually expect list comprehension to be the fastest thing around in python. The benchmarks are proving my expectations to be wrong :-)

Comment: @zmo that's why we benchmark :) fyi, I think `sorted(ll1i+ll2i)` is going to prove faster than calling list on each one

Comment: as I've ran my tests using python3, ll1i and ll2i are `zip()` objects/generators that can't be added together. You either need to `itertools.chain()` them or `list()` each of them first. And yes, I know the OP specified py2.7 :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your existing lists are already sorted, you can use `heapq.merge` on generator expressions that add the tags to your list items.

```
import heapq

test = heapq.merge(((i, "l1") for i in l1), ((i, "l2") for i in l2))
```

`test` will be a generator object that yields sorted value/tag tuples. If you need to make a combined list (rather than just iterating over the values), you can call `list()` on the generator.